# Vodafone Mobile Connect card driver

Tags: 3g, vodafone

I wish to install my 3G usb stick in Ubuntu, but I had no success. Couple years ago I downloaded the files from https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=12

Since then, the hard drive crashed, and the downloaded files are lost.

I cannot find the web page now. I have gone through the Vodafone's website without success.

Could someone help me to find Vodafone mobile connect driver (and the driver for SMS as well)?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, you can use archive.org to find archived websites, that no longer work. I found what you are looking for here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140402203937/https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=12

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm struggling with 16.04. It complains about a missing dependency "hal"